# traversal back to the first child of the same parent

Tags: jquery

If I have a list like this

```
<ul class='halo'>  <-first
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li class='world'>2</li>
</ul>
<ul class='halo'>  <-second
    <li>q</li>
    <li>w</li>
    <li>w</li>
</ul>

$(".somewhere").on("click", function() {    
    if ($("ul li:last-child").hasClass("world") {
        $last = $("ul li:last-child");
        $last.removeClass("world");
        $last.closest("ul li:first-child").addClass("world");
     }
});
```

I have a on click event trigger which determine if the li is the last-child of the parent. But since jquery dont have a function for "farthest"....only closest.

so, if its the last child of the ul, I want to select the ul li:first-child without referring the second ul. I dont know why but $(this) is not working/referring to the current node..

How do I traverse to the farthest li in that parent?

Comment: Show your jQuery code. `$(this).closest('ul')` work for you.

Comment: just `$(this).closest('ul.halo')`

Comment: @ArunPJohny for dont know what reason, $(this) is not working as I think because I am not firing an event else I cant explain...

Comment: can you explain better?

Comment: add your jquery code you have tried

Comment: can you share the details of the method where you have this code...

Comment: I have add a simplified version of my codes, hope this will explained

Comment: are you wanting to jump to the first `li` of the next `ul` or the first `li` of the current `ul`?

Comment: @DelightedD0D latter. to the first li of the current ul

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If I understand you correctly**, something like this should work:

```js
$('#someOtherElement').click(function() {
  var li = $('#container').find('li.world'); // cache the currently selected li
  var lis = li.parent().find('li'); // get all the lis in this ul
  lis.removeClass('world');
  li.addClass('world'); // this is probably handled elsewhere in your code 
  var cur = lis.index(li); // get the index of the clicked li 
  if (cur >= lis.length - 1) { // check if is the last li in this ul
    li.removeClass("world"); // if so move back to the first li in this ul
    lis.eq(0).addClass("world")
  };
});


// handle normal link clicks, elsewhere in your own code
$('#container li').click(function() {
  var li = $(this)
  var lis = li.parent().find('li');
  lis.removeClass('world');
  li.addClass('world'); 
});
```

```css
.world {
  color: red;
}
#someOtherElement {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someOtherElement">
  click in here
</div>
<div id="container">
  <ul class='halo'>
    <li class='world'>Some text</li>
    <li class=''>Some text</li>
    <li class=''>Some text</li>
    <li class=''>Some text</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='halo'>
    <li>q</li>
    <li>w</li>
    <li>w</li>
    <li>w</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If the on click event was not directly under the ul which is in another div, how could I do the above effect?

Comment: somehow I cant get "someotherelement" to trigger on click...i dont get why this line "lis.eq(0).addClass("world")" will not refer back to the "Some text" since my eq(0) go back to the first li ...and ignore all parent...li.eq(0)

Comment: although I dont know why it works at this moment, but the codes work!!

Comment: I made a small tweak to the '$('#container li').click()'  part, though I dont think you're really using that part

Comment: I know this is too much to ask...if you can, can you tell me why lis.parent.find will not return all li in all ul? this is a mysterious to me

Comment: Because `var li = $('#container').find('li.world');` returns the `li` element that currently has the class `world` (presumably the currently selected `li`) Then `var lis = li.parent().find('li');` gets the parent of that selected `li` (the current `ul`) then returns all of the `li` elements within that parent, essentially the clicked `li` and all of it's immediate siblings. If you want all the of the `li`s you can do `var lis = $('#container li');` but its hard to say not fully understanding your use case

Comment: Nice twist you have there. I didnt know it will behaviour like this way...I have tried closest ul children(first-child) but it selected the second ul li as well..